# cut command seems not to work in a pipe

Tags: grep, cut

I am able to filter out jobs which got stuck in our queueing system with:

```
> qjobs | grep "racon" 
       5240703 racon-3/utg001564l-racon-3.fasta  H   1     1   0     10.0   0.0    150   :03   
       5241418 racon-3/utg002276l-racon-3.fasta  H   1     1   0     10.0   0.0    150   :02   
       5241902 racon-3/utg002759l-racon-3.fasta  H   1     1   0     10.0   0.0    150   :03   
       5242060 racon-3/utg002919l-racon-3.fasta  H   1     1   0     10.0   0.0    150   :04   
       5242273 racon-3/utg003133l-racon-3.fasta  H   1     1   0     10.0   0.0    150   :03   
       5242412 racon-3/utg003270l-racon-3.fasta  H   1     1   0     10.0   0.0    150   :04   
       5242466 racon-3/utg003325l-racon-3.fasta  H   1     1   0     10.0   0.0    150   :03
```

However, `qjobs | grep "racon" | cut -d " " -f2` did not return e.g. `racon-3/utg003325l-racon-3.fasta`. What did I miss?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Every space counts towards the field number, even leading and consecutive ones. Hence, you need to use `-f9` instead of `-f2`. Alternatively, you can use `awk '{ print $2 }'` in place of the cut command entirely.

Comment: If OP is going to use `awk` anyway, they can fold it together with the `grep` operation: `qjobs | awk '/racon/ { print "$2" }'`.

Answer (score 1):

If the output is consistent in its spacing

```
qjobs | grep "racon" | cut -c 16-47
```

would produce output like

```
racon-3/utg002276l-racon-3.fasta
```

---

If you want the first column, which looks like a PID or some other identifier, then:

```
qjobs | grep "racon" | awk ' { print $1 } '
```

---

If you're looking for the **utg002276l**  part which looks something like a username:

```
qjobs | grep "racon" | awk -F'[/-]' ' { print $3 } '
```

This makes awk use the slash and dash characters as field separators, and then prints the third column.

Answer (score 0):

You could squeeze all the spaces into one:

```
qjobs | grep "racon" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d " " -f3
```